# Managing Dynamically created User Controls events

Tags: vb.net, class, events

I have a **User Control** that is Dynamically created. It has to raise a `Mouse_Move` event & `Mouse_Down` event.

How to manage events for **Multiple User Control** that are created dynamically. I was considering using a list of user controls to track the controls. But I do not know how to setup the events properly.

```
Public Class UserControl1
    Public Structure Porportions
        Dim width_Percent As Double
        Dim Height_percent As Double
        Dim X_Location_Percent As Double
        Dim Y_Location_Percent As Double
    End Structure
    
    Dim Pipe As Porportions
    Dim guage1 As Porportions
    Dim guage2 As Porportions

    Public start_pos As Point
    Public move_offset As Point
    Public Client_Point As Point

    Public Pipe_Source As Excel
    Public Pipe_Data As DataSet
    Public Pipe_Properties As Pipe
    Private Pipe_ID As String

    ' Public Event Pipe_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Public Event Pipe_MouseMove1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Public Event Pipe_MouseDown1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove 
        RaiseEvent Pipe_MouseMove1(sender, e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
        RaiseEvent Pipe_MouseDown1(sender, e)
    End Sub

Public Class Form1
    Private pipe_cnt As Integer = 0
    Private start_position As Point
    Private MoveOffset As Point
    Private Mouse_Position As Point
    Private WithEvents pp As UserControl1
    
    Private Sub Pipe_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles pp.Pipe_MouseMove1
        Dim dx As Integer
        Dim dy As Integer
        Dim m_loc As Point
        Dim scrn As Point
        
            m_loc = New Point(e.Location)
            Mouse_Position = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
            scrn = PointToScreen(Mouse_Position)
            Mouse_Position = PointToClient(Mouse_Position)    
            dx = start_position.X - Mouse_Position.X
            dy = start_position.Y - Mouse_Position.Y
            MoveOffset = New Point(dx, dy)

        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            Try
                pp.Location = New Point(pp.Left + e.X, pp.Top + e.Y)
                pp.Location = New Point(pp.Left + e.X, pp.Top + e.Y)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
        
    End Sub

    Private Sub Pipe_MouseDown1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles pp.Pipe_MouseDown1
        start_position = New Point(pp.Location)
    End Sub
```

Comment: AddHandler() is what you're after I think

Answer (score 0):

What I understand that you want to use an same event for multiple user controls. There are many methods to achieve this.

#### Method 1 (Easiest):

Just put handler events after `Handles` clause and separate them by commas `,`. See example:

```
Private Sub MouseMove_Event(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Pipe.MouseMove, PictureBox1.MouseMove  
    MsgBox("MouseMove")
End Sub

Private Sub Click_Event(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Pipe.Click, PictureBox1.Click
    MsgBox("Click")
End Sub

Private Sub MouseDown_Event(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Pipe.MouseDown, PictureBox1.MouseDown 
    MsgBox("MouseDown")
End Sub
```

#### Method 2 (burden):

Create and collect all `controls` in a `array of controls` and then create events in a `foreach` loop.

- Create `Sub` that gets `array of controls` and add `handlers` using `foreach` loop.

```
    Private Sub CreateHandlers(Controls() As Control)
        For Each control As Control In Controls
            Me.Controls.Add(control)
            AddHandler control.Click, AddressOf Click_Event
            AddHandler control.MouseMove, AddressOf MouseMove_Event
            AddHandler control.MouseDown, AddressOf MouseDown_Event
        Next
    End Sub
```

- Your events

```
    Private Sub Click_Event(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'Handle Click events here
    End Sub

    Private Sub MouseMove_Event(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'Handle MouseMove events here
    End Sub

    Private Sub MouseDown_Event(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'Handle MouseDown events here
    End Sub
```

Create controls dynamically and just call `CreateHandlers(controls)` at end

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim pictureBox1 As PictureBox = New PictureBox _
         With {
                  .Size = New Size(100, 100),
                  .Location = New Point(0, 0),
                  .BackColor = Color.Black
              }

        Dim panel1 As Panel = New Panel _
         With {
                  .Size = New Size(100, 100),
                  .Location = New Point(100, 0),
                  .BackColor = Color.Red
              }

        Dim tableLayoutPanel1 As TableLayoutPanel = New TableLayoutPanel _
        With {
                 .Size = New Size(100, 100),
                 .Location = New Point(200, 0),
                 .BackColor = Color.Green
             }

        Dim controls() As Control = {pictureBox1, panel1, tableLayoutPanel1}
        CreateHandlers(controls)
    End Sub
End Class
```